# import a python file that create a window when main window button clicks

Tags: python, import, tkinter, interface, window

I am creating 2 window in my program and i am using two class, since the code is complex, i separate it in 2 different python file. After i imported the second window file, how can i make sure it open without having this error which show in this picture [image]

The original result should look like this after the new window button clicked:
[image]

Coding for Main Window:

```
from tkinter import *
import classGUIProgram
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.geometry("600x400+30+30")
        self.wButton = Button(self, text='newWindow', command =     self.OnButtonClick)
        self.wButton.pack()

    def OnButtonClick(classGUIProgram):
        classGUIProgram.top = Toplevel()
        master = Tk()
        b = classGUIProgram.HappyButton(master)
        master.mainloop()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Window(None)

    window.title("title")

    window.mainloop()
```

Coding for Second Window:

```
from tkinter import *
class HappyButton:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.printButton = Button(frame, text="Print message", command=self.printMessage)
        self.printButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text="Quit", command= quit)
        self.quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.downloadHistoryCB=Checkbutton(frame, text="Download History")
        self.downloadHistoryCB.pack(side=LEFT)

    def printMessage(self):
        print("Wow this actually worked!")

master = Tk()
b = HappyButton(master)
master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating extra `Tk` windows. Here is an example of using `Toplevel` widgets and another file.

**mainWindow.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import secondWindow as sW

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Main Window")
        self.geometry("600x400+30+30")

        tk.Button(self, text = "New Window", command = self.new_window).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text = "Close Window", command = self.close).pack()

        self._second_window = None

    def new_window(self):
        # This prevents multiple clicks opening multiple windows
        if self._second_window is not None:
            return

        self._second_window = sW.SubWindow(self)

    def close(self):
        # Destory the 2nd window and reset the value to None
        if self._second_window is not None:
            self._second_window.destroy()
            self._second_window = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = MainWindow()
    window.mainloop()
```

**secondWindow.py**

```
import tkinter as tk

class SubWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.title("Sub Window")
        self.geometry("400x300+30+30")
        # Change what happens when you click the X button
        # This is done so changes also reflect in the main window class
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', master.close)

        tk.Button(self, text = "Print", command = self.printMessage).pack()

    def printMessage(self):
        print("Wow this actually worked!")
```

When using another file be sure to not have any global code you don't want running. Your classes don't have to inherit from `Tk` and `Toplevel`, this is just an example. But you need to ensure you only ever have one instance of `Tk` otherwise you get the behaviour you encountered